# I have the error 503, No Shard Available Action Exception with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I am having problems when I am looking for a register inside of an index and the message is the next:

```
TransportError: TransportError(503, u'NoShardAvailableActionException[[new_gompute_history][2] null]; nested: IllegalIndexShardStateException[[new_gompute_history][2] CurrentState[POST_RECOVERY] operations only allowed when started/relocated]; ')
```

This comes when I am searching by an id inside of an index.

The health of my cluster is green:

```
GET _cat/health?v

epoch      timestamp cluster status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign 
1438678496 10:54:56  juan    green           5         4    212 106    0    0        0 


GET _cat/allocation?v

shards disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host    ip         node                   
    53     3.1gb     16.8gb       20gb           15 bc10-05 10.8.5.15  Anomaloco              
    53     6.4gb     80.8gb     87.3gb            7 bc10-03 10.8.5.13  Algrim the Strong      
     0        0b                                    l8a     10.8.0.231 logstash-l8a-5920-4018 
    53     6.4gb     80.8gb     87.3gb            7 bc10-03 10.8.5.13  Harry Leland           
    53     3.1gb     16.8gb       20gb           15 bc10-05 10.8.5.15  Hypnotia
```

I solved putting a a sleep time between consecutive PUTs, but I do not like this solution

Comment: Your issue might be related to this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/12600 ?

Comment: I think no, but  it is so unusual because this error appears in different machines and if the consecutive PUT have a sleep interval between them this error not appears or if I change the machine where I do the PUT to do the consecutive data injection.

Comment: @Val: Could you please see the following link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997171/org-elasticsearch-action-noshardavailableactionexception-in-elasticsearch) I have posted a question related to this question. Please help if I am missing any configuration related to cluster.

Comment: Seems like this error could mean a number of things. I've encountered it when attempting to use a point in time that had expired.