# org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I try to post a few documents to an elastic search dated index, the below exception is thrown and insertion is incomplete.

org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException

elasticsearch verion used is : elasticsearch-1.7.2

Exception in detail:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: [test_events_20170805][0] null
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction.perform(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:175)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction.start(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:155)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:89)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:55)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:258)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:240)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleRequest(MessageChannelHandler.java:222)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:114)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
```

Thanks in advance!

Below is my cluster's health:
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "test-services",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 377,
  "active_shards" : 377,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 377,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

Below is the template for index creation

```
{
"template" : "test_events_*"
     , "settings" : {
        "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "std_with_spaces": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
            }
        }
    }
    , "number_of_shards" : 1
}
, "mappings" :
{ "TestEvent" : { "dynamic": "strict", "_meta" : { "authority": "com.test", "type": "published", "version": "1" }, "properties" : {
"aliasName" : { "type" : "string", "description" : "The aliasName is free text human readable name." }
, "description" : { "type" : "string", "description" : "The description is a free human readable text describing or naming the object." }
, "id" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "description" : "Master resource identifier" }
, "association" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "description" : "Contains links or IDs to associated documents and content." }
, "name" : { "type" : "string", "analyzer" : "std_with_spaces", "description" : "The name is any free human readable and possibly non unique text naming the object." }
, "tag" : { "type" : "string" }
, "recordDateTime" : { "type" : "date" }
, "systemOfRecord" : { "type" : "string", "analyzer" : "std_with_spaces" }
, "createdDateTime" : { "type" : "date" }
 }}}
}
```

Below is the snippet for data insertion script:

```
PUT /website/blog/123 /* this might not be correct, written for an idea*/
{
  "id": "EDE-1",
  "description":  "Just trying this out...",
  "createdDateTime":  "2017-08-28T02:12:21",
  "recordDateTime":  "2017-08-28T02:12:21",
  "aliasName": "test",
  "name": "test_name",
  "association": "test_association",
  "tag": "tag1",
  "systemOfRecord": "record1"
}
```

Note: data insertion snippet is a mock data I created. But as a whole, data is submitted to my application in csv file. The application converts the csv data into json object and inserts it into dated index.

Comment: You should check (and possibly update your question to add) your [cluster health stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/cluster-health.html)

Comment: @dshockley: I have added the cluster health.. Could you please go through the question.

Comment: I was hoping to see no active shards, but that's not the case. You'll have to add more information before someone can help you -- I would start with updating with exactly the requests you're using to create the index and attempt to index the documents.

Comment: @dshockley: I have updated the question with the index create and insert scripts. could you please check the question.

Comment: I've experimented  a bit (albeit with 1.7.6, because that's what I can find a docker image for), and I cannot reproduce your issue -- is it possible you're low in disk space? (See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/disk.html)

Comment: @dshockley: No, the disk has sufficient space. One thing I observed is, the first time when I try to index the documents it is incomplete(i.e. 1200 of 3000 documents indexed). Immediately, when I try to re-index the same documents it's complete (all 3000 documents are indexed). That means, exception is thrown on first time and the second time the indexing process is complete. Is that something, elasticsearch has any limit of allocating shards to the indices. Because, I am trying to index 3000 documents into dated indices for which 100 to 200 indices are created depending on the date.

Comment: My guess now is maybe a thread pool is the issue? I do not know which pool it would be (possibly index?) -- if that's the case you may be able to resolve it by setting the queue_size larger. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/modules-threadpool.html) -- also if it's possible you should probably use bulk instead of index api.

Comment: @dshockley: sorry for the delay in commenting back had some environmental issues with my application on setting queue_size which consumed little time to resolve. These are the Thread Pool settings and if I try to increase the queue_size somehow the elasticsearch is behaving weird. threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 24
threadpool.index.queue_size: 200

Comment: @dshockley: sorry for the delay in commenting back had some environmental issues with my application on setting queue_size which consumed little time to resolve. These are the pool settings and if I try to increase the queue_size somehow the elasticsearch is behaving weird. threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 24
threadpool.index.queue_size: 200. I cannot even increase the size to 250. Is there any restriction for it? Bulk API can be used but for that a lot of changes required in app and which is the very low priority solution. If I can do something with settings is fine.

Comment: You could also try changing refresh_interval (in the index settings) to some longer time period (maybe 30s instead of 1s which is default I think). It means you have to wait 30s before docs are available for search, and also if there's some catastrophic failure you can lose data that was indexed in that 30s, but it might help (and might not). Obviously you could also increase resources to solve the problem...

Comment: I assume you can't upgrade to ES 2.x or 5.x? It was awhile ago, but I remember some of these kinds of problems getting better on upgrade to ES 2, and also logs were improved. I imagine you already would have done that if you could though. :)

Comment: @dshockley: I tried refresh_interval with 30 and even with -1 and had no changes in the result. Tried to set wait_for_status=yellow in the request and still no positive result.  "http://192.168.23.10:9200/_cluster/health/test_index?wait_for_status=yellow". Is having more columns effects the indexing? Cause, the index has nearly 100 columns and nearly 6000 documents.

Comment: Just for test purposes, could you try indexing with some time between index requests (like maybe 500ms)? Also you could try creating the all indexes in advance, and then indexing everything (again for test purposes). I don't know would suspect more fields contributes to resource usage, but I don't think 100 fields/6000 documents is a lot.

Comment: @dshockley: Yeah, we are trying to sort out the issue. Got multiple new settings and planning to increase the available resources. As our target is to ingest 5 million documents without fail. Will definitely update the question once I got it sorted out. Thanks for your help. Definitely will come back, if I face any issues still.

Comment: Just for point of comparison, we ingest ~15 million documents/day, plus updates on each doc several times (and keep ~700GB of data at a time), with 2 data nodes with 30GB memory each (plus 3 master nodes with very low resources). We've optimized for indexing, and basically never lose data or fail indexing, but complex aggregation queries are very slow.